# How to map entities with Hibernate XML in joint tables

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I'm a beginner in Hibernate and found a problem in mapping 3 tables with 2 entities.

the SQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  userid int unsigned auto_increment,
  username varchar(20) not null,
  password varchar(64) not null,
  primary key (userid)
);

CREATE TABLE roles (
  roleid int unsigned auto_increment,
  rolename varchar(10) not null,
  description varchar(255) not null
  primary key (roleid)
);

CREATE TABLE userroles (
  userid int unsigned not null,
  roleid int unsigned not null,
  primary key (userid,roleid),
  foreign key (userid) references users (userid),
  foreign key (roleid) references roles (roleid)
);
```

current mapping xmls

User.hbm.xml

```
<class name="com.model.User" table="users">
  <id name="userId" column="userid">
    <generator class="native"/>
  </id>
  <property name="userName" column="username"/>
  <property name="password" column="password"/>
</class>
```

Role.hbm.xml

```
<class name="com.model.Role" table="roles">
  <id name="roleId" column="roleid">
    <generator class="native"/>
  </id>
  <property name="roleName" column="rolename"/>
  <property name="description" column="description"/>
</class>
```

please also advise how to create the entity java files. Thanks

Comment: It's really not clear what you are asking here. What is the problem? Are you struggling to map the association between these types or not clear on how the HBM files relate to java class files?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are having trouble mapping the third table. You'll need to use composite keys for your third table. Here are few links you might find helpful:- http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#d0e2177
http://www.theserverside.com/discussions/thread.tss?thread_id=22638

If you still have trouble creating the files, feel free to add comment in the answer and I'll try to help you further.
To create java files, simply create the file with getters and setters and use the get methods to extract data and set methods to input new data.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i know the composite keys, but what i want to do with the third table, is to create multiplicity relationships with the first two tables, one-to-one relationship with 'users' and many-to-one relationship with 'roles'